# Push values without keys to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

In react-native I'm trying to push values from the code below to an array without the keys because the component (react-native-table-component) I'm using will only accept an array of strings or numbers and not objects with key value pairs.  I'm so close to figuring it out but I'm getting stuck!

**Structure of response.data**

```
response.data = {
  "Hours": 234,
  "Minutes": 343,
  "Days": 23,
  "Months": 4
}
```

**Code to receive response.data and push to array**

```
  toScreenTwo = async () => {
    const { isLoggedIn, user} = this.state;
    try {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {                 
        const response = await http.post('/v1/signup/user', {
          user,
        })
        for (var value in response.data) {
          this.state.tableData2.push(value);
        }
        console.log('response', this.state.tableData2);
      }



      await this.setState({
        modalVisible: false,
        friendsModalVisible: false
      });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("error ", err);
    }
}
```

**Current Code Result**

The code above, is currently push only the keys to the array tableData2 when I want to push only the values to the array tableData2

**Array format that react-native-table-component accepts**

```
 tableData: [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c']
      ]
```

It seems that react-native-table-component needs to be passed an array with at least one array nested within it

**Errors**

[image: Error Message]

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

Comment: What is `response.data`? Aka, what is `value` inside the loop? You might need something like `this.state.tableData2.push( value.somePropertyName );`.

Comment: Please add context. What happens when you run your code? I'm assuming this is React. What components are you using and why? You say you are stuck, are you getting an error message? Is it not doing what you expect? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: `push` doesn't return a promise, you shouldn't use an `await` in that loop

Comment: 1) Where are you stuck? Arrays in JavaScript are indexed but do not have keys. (2) `Array.push()` is not an asynchronous function, remove the `await` before it in your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this `response.data` is an object containing data as follow:

```
{
    key: 1,
    key2, "Ele", and so on.
}
```

You can use the function `Objec.values` to get the array of values `[1, "Ele"]` and the function `apply` to pass those values as params to the function `push`.

```
let values = Object.values(response.data);
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.state.tableData2, values);
```

This code snippet explains a little how the functions `apply` and `Object.values` work.

```js
let myObj = {
  "Hours": 234,
  "Minutes": 343,
  "Days": 23,
  "Months": 4
};

let array = [];
let values = Object.values(myObj);
Array.prototype.push.apply(array, values);
console.log(array);
```

Even less complicated, just assign the result of `Object.values` if the attribute `this.state.tableData2` can be overwritten.

```
this.state.tableData2 = Object.values(response.data);
```

Comment: That makes sense and I completely thought it would work but it's not for some reason!  I tried this.state.tableData2 = Object.values(response.data); but its not working. I think its an issue with the react-native component I'm using.  I still get the following error in the picture I just added to my original post.  

I'm also included the console log of a hardcoded tableData2 array that works with this react-native component and the console log from tableData2 when setting it to Object.values(response.data)

Comment: I wrapped object.values in [] like so and I was able to figure it out! 

 let values = [Object.values(myObj)];

Thanks for your help!  Do you want to edit your answer and I'll accept it?  I'd edit it for you but it feels weird to edit work posted under someone else's username

Comment: @bzlight do this `this.state.tableData2.push(Object.values(responde.data))` it’s a better logic.